# rails 5 api how to fix validation response?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

on the screenshot as you can see the response of validation comes with this exception and trace. 
i searched piratically all the internet so properly show the error message and the status and i did found nothing that fixed it.

the closest that i reached is using model serializer but the problem persists.

```
def create
    @user = User.create!(user_params)


    if @user.save

      render json: @user.auth_token, status: 201

    else

      render_json_validation_error @user




    end
  end
```

here the code:

```
def render_json_validation_error(resource)
    render json: resource, status: 422,  
    serializer: ActiveModel::Serializer::ErrorSerializer

 end
```

someone has nay idea how take off this trace and exception?

[image]

Comment: Can you show your controller code, would like to look at the render line ?

Comment: sure @KedarnagMukanahallipatna is there

Comment: Why not just do `render json: @user.errors.full_messages.first, status: 422`

Comment: @KedarnagMukanahallipatna the same, i've tried just render json:user.errors, status: 422 and the same.

maybe is the rails version, is 5.1.4

Comment: Ok have you tried doing this ? `render serializer: ErrorSerializer, json: {:status => 422, :errors => @user.errors}`

Comment: i gonna try a moment

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180042/discussion-between-kedarnag-mukanahallipatna-and-lula).

Comment: @KedarnagMukanahallipatna the same, seems to be the api problem, what you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is with using `create!`. If you add `!` and validation fails it will raise an error with a backtrace. Try to remove `create!` and instead use either `create` or `new` as it would be more appropriate to your use case. Basically you initiate a model instance, then try to `.save` it and once `save` returns false you render a validation error messages:

```
def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)

    if @user.save
      render json: @user.auth_token, status: 201
    else
      render_json_validation_error @user
    end
end
```